# Querying 2 datatables in a dataset

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I have 2 datatables named 'dst' and 'dst2'. they are located in the dataset 'urenmat'. 
The mayority of the data is in 'dst'. this however contains a column named 'werknemer'. It contains a value which corresponds to a certain row in 'dst2'. This column is named 'nummer'.

What i need is a way to left outer join both datatables where dst.werknemer and dst2.nummer are linked, and a new datatable is created which contains 'dst2.naam' linked to 'dst.werknemer' along with all the other columns from 'dst'.

I have looked everywhere and still can't seem te find the right answer to my question. several sites provide a way using LINQ in this situation. I have tried using LINQ but i am not so skilled at this.

I tried using the 101 LINQ Samples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
urenmat = dataset.
dst =  a, b, c, d, werknemer.
dst2 = nummer, naam.
```

I used the following code from '101'.

```
            var query =
            from contact in dst.AsEnumerable()
            join order in dst2.AsEnumerable()
            on contact.Field<string>("werknemer") equals
            order.Field<string>("nummer")
            select new
            {
                a = order.Field<string>("a"),
                b = order.Field<string>("b"),
                c = order.Field<string>("c"),
                d = order.Field<string>("d"),
                naam = contact.Field<decimal>("naam")};
```

I however don't know what to change 'contact' and 'order' to and i can't seem to find out how to save it to a datatable again.

I am very sorry if these are stupid questions but i have tried to solve it myself but it appears i'm stupid:P. Thank for the help in advance!

PS. i am using C# to code, the dataset and datatables are typed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to produce a projected dataset of `dst` left outer joined to `dst2` you can use this LINQ expression (sorry i don't really work in LINQ query syntax so you'll have to use this lambda syntax instead).

```
var query = dst.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupJoin(dst2.AsEnumerable(), x => x.Field<string>("werknemer"), x => x.Field<string>("nummer"), (contact, orders) => new { contact, orders })
    .SelectMany(x => x.orders.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, order) => new
    {
        a = order.Field<string>("a"),
        b = order.Field<string>("b"),
        c = order.Field<string>("c"),
        d = order.Field<string>("d"),
        naam = x.contact.Field<decimal>("naam")
    });
```

because this is a projected dataset you cannot simply *save back to the datatable*. If saving is desired then you would want to load the affected row, update the desired fields, then save the changes.

```
// untyped
var row = dst.Rows.Find(keyValue);
// typed
var row = dst.FindBy...(keyValue);

// update the field
row.SetField("a", "some value");
// save only this row's changes
row.AcceptChanges();

// or after all changes to the table have been made, save the table
dst.AcceptChanges();
```

Normally if you need to perform loading and saving of (projected) data, an ORM (like entity framework, or LINQ-to-SQL) would be the best tool. However, you are using `DataTable`'s in this case and I'm not sure if you can link an ORM to these (though it seems like it would probably be possible).